# SQL 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword' on a recently added table column (edit: column name is reserved word)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table contains the following columns:

- id (int)
- errorDate (datetime)
- Data nvarchar(100)
- Function (newly added column, nvarchar(100))
- fileName(same as Function newly added, no problem with this one, though)

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2876.0 (X64)   May 30 2013 10:18:43   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  14.0.17277.0

My query goes like that:

```
select * from dbo.InstallationErrorLog  
where data = 'Input string was not in a correct format.' 
   and ErrorDate > GETDATE()-90 
   and Function ='ProcessTblFromCSV'
```

The query returns the error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Function'.

Comment: `Function` is a keyword. Use it in square brackets `[Function]`

Comment: Best to avoid Reserved Words   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function` is a keyword in T-SQL.

Try surrounding it with brackets:

```
select * from dbo.InstallationErrorLog  
where data = 'Input string was not in a correct format.' 
   and ErrorDate > GETDATE()-90 
   and [Function] ='ProcessTblFromCSV'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need square bracks `[]` around `function` column :

```
select * 
from dbo.InstallationErrorLog  
where data = 'Input string was not in a correct format.' and 
      ErrorDate > GETDATE()-90  and 
      [Function] ='ProcessTblFromCSV';
```

However, it is not recommended to use name `function`, it is reserved keyword. The second thing, i would use `dateadd()` here is a [blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) on this instead of subtraction (`-90`):

So, you can do instead :

```
select * 
from dbo.InstallationErrorLog  
where data = 'Input string was not in a correct format.' and 
      ErrorDate > DATEADD(DAY, -90,  GETDATE()) and 
      [Function] ='ProcessTblFromCSV';
```

Comment: Referring to your second recommendation, what is the reason?